# Downloading a directory from S3 works with Java SDK but not AWS CLI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

## Background

I need to download a directory from s3 using the AWS Command Line Interface.  Whenever I attempt to download a file using the CLI I get an access denied error.  However it downloads fine using the Java SDK.  I cannot view the permissions associated with the key so I have to troubleshoot this as a black box. I included the code samples below

## AWS CLI

I am using the following command in PowerShell to download the file through the AWS CLI

```
aws s3 cp s3://ec-sis-integration-test/fiscal/ .\
```

This command throws the following error

> download failed: s3://ec-sis-integration-test/fiscal/ to ./ [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\users\cmaggiul\Desktop\'

## Java SDK

To troubleshoot this I created a sample Java application that attempts to download a directory from s3.  The code is included below

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(s3Client).build();

File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "/Desktop"); 

MultipleFileDownload download =  transferManager.downloadDirectory(bucket, directory, desktop);
download.waitForCompletion();
```

This code successfully downloads the directory using the sample `AWS_PROFILE`

## Troubleshooting steps

I have tried the following solutions

1. Attempted to download empty directories and directories that are not empty
2. Tried to add the `--recursive` flag to the CLI command
3. Tried to change the ACL on files within the directory ( when I was attempting to download a non-empty directory )
4. Tried to create the directory with the same AWS_PROFIlE I am using to download and with a different AWS_PROFILE
5. I set up a docker image, download and installed the aws cli and set up the environment variables.  I then ran

`sudo aws s3 cp s3://ec-sis-integration-test/fiscal/ ./`

And received the following error

> download failed: s3://ec-sis-integration-test/fiscal/ to ./ [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/root/aws-test/.9AA88F60' -> '/root/aws-test/'

But it works fine if I try and download a specific file

```
aws s3 cp s3://ec-sis-integration-test/fiscal/collections/COLL_20201228_1-EXP ./
```

It also works fine in PowerShell if I download a specific file

## Question

Why can I download the file using the same AWS_PROFILE using the Java SDK but not the CLI?

Comment: You're doing two different things. The awscli invocation attempts to copy a single object (whose key is `fiscal/`). The Java SDK invocation attempts to download an entire folder (strictly all keys with a given prefix of `fiscal/`). To tell the awscli to download all objects under `fiscal/`, add `--recursive`. Also, I would simply use `.` as the target.

Comment: @jarmod when I add the --recursive key I get the following error fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied.  Do I need to add that permission?

Comment: Believe that you need to have `s3:ListBucket` on the bucket.

Comment: Ok let me see if I can get that added and retry.  If it works I'll respond and you can write an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\users\cmaggiul\Desktop\
```

This is unrelated to AWS. Your script doesn't have permissions to write to that directory.

Comment: It looks like that, but I really don't think that is the issue.  I'm opening Powershell as administrator and running it manually.  I just ran it in a few different locations to verify ( in root C, in c:\users\administrator, etc )

Comment: try to spin a linux virtual machine and check whether permissions issue appears there. My bet would be that it indeed is some Windows FS bs, since it treats C drive with special gloves

Comment: Ok Ill set up the parameters in a docker image and try right now

Comment: please see my update.  It does not work in a docker container either.  It does, however download a specific file on windows and on linux in the same directories im using

Comment: It wont download the directory in linux either, granted it throws a different error.  However it will download specific files to the directories im using in both windows and linux

Comment: This is probably related to directory structure inside the bucket, but in the end if you can download files this is not related to AWS permissions

Comment: There are no permissions related to directories?

Comment: No, AWS_PROFILE or anything AWS related doesn't influence permissions or FS issues on your local machine. CLI would have mentioned any AWS issues explicitly. There *could* be some issues with specific objects, but unless you find the reason why CLI can't write we won't see that